# How to navigate a viewcontroller (which is made in swift) in Objective c xib class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessagesViewController library for chat purpose. Chat may contains urls. If user click on the url the url is opening in safari.

I want to open the url in my own View Controller which have the webview. But I don't know how can I navigate the viewcontroller in objective c which is made in swift.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView
shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
         inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
     interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction
{
   // Navigate to next VC
    return NO;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how can I navigate the viewcontroller in objective c
>   which is made in swift.

`Use bridging header` to make your swift viewcontroller make visible in objective-c code, then you can push the viewcontroller using the ordinary procedure.

```
MySwiftVC *vc = [MySwiftVC init....];
vc.someProperty = Blah blah...;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
```

Comment: I am using JSQMessagesLibrary, I want to do navigation in library but How can I do this?

Comment: You need to subclass it and override the function that opens url in Safari and use customized control say `CustomJSQMessagesLibrary` instead of `JSQMessagesLibrary` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

for framework (e. Cocoapods)

```
@import frameworkName
```

for project (e. Manually drag)

```
#import "projectName-Swift.h"
```

and use it

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to access your Objective-C classes you need a Bridging header where you have to import your Objective-C header files.

if you want to access Swift classes in Objective-C you have to import swift.h which is a header file generated automatically by Xcode remember. Complete name for your swift.h file will be (yourprojectname-Swift.h) e.g `Example-Swift.h`

```
#import "yourprojectname-Swift.h"
```

Now you can access your ViewController in your objective-C

Now you can use your swiftViewControllers the same way as your doing your objective-C

```
// Name of your Swift View Controller
YourSwiftViewController *yourSwiftVC = [[YourSwiftViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourSwiftVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I want to do this in third party library, I have install pods for this purpose.

Comment: In that case the third party library must have a function which you can override that or it may Post a Notification or some kind of block.  or does it directly opens the url by it self without notifying you?

Comment: When I clicked on url it automatically opened the url in safari.

Comment: I think you have to look at the delegates in there documentation [JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellDelegate Protocol Reference] (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.3.4/Protocols/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellDelegate.html) I don't know how you save your urls and I didn't find anything in the documentation of JSQMessages which points that they will open any View. don't forget they have delegate for tableViewCells as well you have to dig deeper in those delegates

Answer (score 0):

You need bridge between Swift and objective-c,

1. Add @objc in swift class define like: `@objc class Abc{}`.
2. Build your project so Xcode can automatically generate bridge file for you.
3. Import `"YourProject-Swift.h"` in objective-c file

Now you can call swift class in objective-C.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your swift ViewController has a URL variable like:

```
var url: URL!
```

and loadRequest with the url.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

include the Swift class reference as follow in Objective-C class

```
#import "<productName>-Swift.h"
```

in your context, Objective-C Controller when handling textView shouldInteractWithURL

```
SwiftWebViewController *vc = [[SwiftWebViewController alloc] init];
vc.url = URL;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

return NO;
```